# Не коректно работает мультиязычность в Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, apache2, joomla3

После установки quickstart одностраничного шаблона и настройки языков - сайт не корректно работает. Если в плагине *Система - Фильтр языка* не включить опцию *Удалять префикс языка по умолчанию* - сайт выдает ошибку 404.

Кто сталкивался, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел выход из ситуации. 
Если у кого-то будет подобная проблема:
1) В настройках apache включаем директиву AllowOverride all ( стоит none по умолчанию )
2) Подключаем mod_rewrite и mod_expires.
3) Делаем рестарт сервера.

Всё.